# Two smooth maps are related by another smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $U$ be an open subset of a smooth manifold $M$ and $f,g:U\rightarrow M$ be smooth maps.

Can we always (When can we) find a smooth map $\Phi: U\rightarrow U$ such that $g=f\circ \Phi$??

I have nothing much to say on this. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: An easy counterexample is the map $f\colon U\to M, x\mapsto p$, where $p$ is a fixed point in $M$. Obiously, there are many maps $g$ which we cannot relate to $f$ in the described way.

Comment: That is nice one. Can you say anything about "when can we"?? @Babelfish

Comment: An easy example where it works out: Consider $\mathrm{id}_U$. If you have a $f$ such that there is $\Phi$ with $\mathrm{id}_U = f \circ \Phi$, then you find a $\Phi_g$ for every $g$. Just use $g=f\circ \Phi \circ g$ (ie $\Phi_g = \Phi \circ g$). That's the case when $f\colon U\to U$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: That is really nice one.. +1 I do not think it would be interesting to consider the case when $f(U)\subseteq U$ and that $f:U\rightarrow U$ is a diffeomorphism.. But I get some idea...  +1

Comment: Hm, but I think it is not true. The composition is not well defined for general $g$. If $g\colon U\to U$ it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the general case, but here are some thoughts:

- If $f$ is a constant map to a point in $M$, there are many maps $g$ which we cannot relate to $g$ in the described way.
- If $f\colon U\to U$ is a diffeomorphism of $U$, then there is an inverse $f^{-1}\colon U\to U$ such that $f\circ f^{-1} = \mathrm{id}_U$. Obviously, we can then relate $f$ to any $g\colon U\to U$ by setting $\Phi = f^{-1} \circ g$. Then we get $g=f\circ f^{-1} \circ g = f\circ \Phi$
- If $f$ and $g$ have disjoint images, there is no chance to find $\Phi$. More precisely, if you have a $\Phi$, then $\Im (g) = \Im(f\circ \Phi) \subset \Im(f)$. So that would be a very easy obstruction.

Note that those points do not really incorporate the smoothness of those maps.

Comment: +1.. your third point gives reasonably good necessary condition...

Comment: $g:U\rightarrow M$... Not $g:U\rightarrow U$...

Comment: No, we need $g\colon U \to U$ or the composition $f^{-1}\circ g$ won't be defined on all $U$.